# Converting string input to a variable for matplotlib.pyplot in Python

Tags: python, string, matplotlib, variables

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
string = input("Please enter a function: ")
```

Here the code that I want to convert. I want to convert this to variable to graph the function. Other part of the code will be:

```
domain = [x for x in range(-10,10)]
range = [string for x in domain]
```

And I want the string in range be variable in order to Python can run the code. For example if a user enter, let's say,

```
string = "x ** 2 + x * 2 + 1"
```

Then I want a method or something that will convert this string to a variable. And in the end I want to get:

```
string = x ** 2 + x * 2 + 1
```

By getting this I can get a plot from matplotlib. Finally code will be:

```
domain = [x for x in range(-10,10)]
range = [x ** 2 + x * 2 + 1 for x in domain]
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You may want to take a look at [SymPy](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorial/index.html), which is a library for symbolic mathematics. Also, when you write `range = ...` you are overwriting the built-in [`range`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range) function so you should use a different variable name

Comment: Thanks a lot! It will work I have just looked at it!

Answer (score 1):

A quick & dirty approach would be to use the native function `eval`. For instance define the following high-order function:

```py
def str_to_func(string):
    return lambda x: eval(string)
```

which can be used in this way:

```py
function = str_to_func(string)
values = [function(x) for x in domain]
plt.plot(domain, values)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I will try this also!